# How/Can C++ lambdas retain inner state?

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a basic lambda that looks like this:

```
auto l = [](){
  int i = 0;
  cout << i++;
}
```

Calling this a bunch of times, will keep printing 0. How can I retain i? Can I do this without functors?

Comment: How can functions retain inner state?

Comment: Maybe you need `static`?

Comment: This thread is informative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323811/what-is-meant-by-retain-state-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 auto l = [](){
   static int i = 0;
// ^^^^^^
   cout << i++;
 }
```

should fix your concerns.

In general functions cannot retain *inner state* without using a local `static` variable. There's no difference with using lambdas actually.

---

If you want to count copies, you can use an ordinary functor class implementation as [@Revolver_Ocelot suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037627/how-can-c-lambdas-retain-inner-state/38037663?noredirect=1#comment63515412_38037663).

Comment: just as a side question, if i'd want to make a copy of l, wouldnt that copy keep the same i variable as l?

Comment: @val Yes, it would keep it, since lambdas of the same type all share this instance of `i`.

Comment: is there a way each instance of l could have its own version of i that they can work with?

Comment: @val There was an interesting question about the values of [inheriting lambdas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024024/what-does-it-mean-to-inherit-from-lambda?s=1|1.3089). I don't know if this helps you into the direction you want.

Comment: Lambdas should be passed by copy (the standard library always passes callable objects by copy). You wouldn't be able to if each instance had its own copy of i.

Comment: @val if you want each copy to have own value, you should write stateful functor yourself (lambda is actually just a syntax sugar for that).

Comment: `mutable` keyword helps storing the state in a lambda

Comment: BE VERY CAREFUL using a local static. It appears the the capture is not re-performed everytime the lambda is created. The lambda appears to be compiled as if it was a global scope function and the static is not re-initialized everytime the lambda is created. This means results in different behavior between using a static and using the newer mutable lambda: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/885#issuecomment-641328578

Answer (score 26):

Depending on what you want to do with this lambda, you might consider the following alternative:

```
auto exec = [i = 0]() mutable { cout << ++i << ' '; };
exec();  // 1
exec();  // 2
auto exec2 = exec; // copy state of lambda
exec2(); // 3
exec();  // 3
```

Using `[]() { static int i = 0; cout << ++i << ' '; };` instead will result in the sequence `1 2 3 4` being printed.

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/gZkQRN)

Comment: Please note: required C++ 14.

Comment: Yeah, wanted to say it doesnt compile on VS2013.

Answer (score 21):

Try to think of a lambda as a class with an `operator()`. How would you retain state in a class? Have a member. Captures are the equivalent here.

```
#include <iostream>
auto l = [i=0]()mutable{
  std::cout << i++;
};
auto l2=l;
int main(){
  l(); // 0
  l(); // 1
  l(); // 2
  l2(); // 0
  l2(); // 1
  l(); // 3
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want `i` to retain its value then you have three options:

1. Declare `i` as a global variable (Bad).
2. Pass previous value of `i` to the function every time (Better).
3. Declare `i` as a `static` variable (Best).

   ```
   auto l = []() { static int i = 0; cout << i++ << endl; };
   l(); l(); l();
   ```

   This will give as output:

   ```
   0
   1
   2
   ```

Comment: I'm not sure that static == best.  A static is impossible to control.

Comment: This state is only initialized once, not every time the lambda is created. It behaves differently than a mutable lambda.